# C# ASP.NET MVC view: problem with retaining model, variable, or ViewBag data when View calls Action repeatedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables, session-state, httpcontext

I have a model for a batter average web app. After entering the player's name and how many games in a series to average, I wish to collect `hits` and `atbats` for each game.  There is a class called `Game` with 2 properties, `hits`, and `atbats` (both integers).  In the batter model, there is a property that is a `List` of type `Game` called `series`.

I wish to display two text boxes, bound to a local instance of `Game.hits` and `Game.atbats`.  I want to cycle through the game series `length` (int) using the same text boxes on the screen until series has the entire list of `hits` and `atbats`.

The problem is trying to accomplish this task and set the List `series`.  I would prefer to have the Action `AddGame` do that, but when I try to repeatedly call the same View and Action, the `length` value doesn't decrement.  I tried decrementing length in the Action and it would only drop by 1 number and stop.  The Hidden's are necessary, I have found, in order to send their values to the Action.

Currently, the action is empty, so I haven't included any code for it.

In the `Models` folder, I have these two classes in one namespace:

```
public class Batter
{
    
    public double average { get; set; }
    public string ?name { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }

    public List<Game> series { get; set; } = new List<Game>();
}

public class Game
{
    public int hits { get; set; }
    public int atbats { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model batterup.Models.Batter
@using batterup.Models

@{
    ViewData["PageTitle"] = "Add Game";
}

<div>
    <h1>@ViewData["PageTitle"]</h1>
    <span>For player @Model.name </span>
    <span> with a game series of @Model.length.</span>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddGame", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        var game = new Game();
      
            @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.name );
            @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.length );
            @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.series );
            @Html.TextBox("hits");<br/>
            @Html.TextBox("atbats");<br/>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        }
    
    }
  
</div>
```

This view does display two textboxes and one button correctly.

How do I conditionally render only this each time I wish to add a new `Game` object to `series`?

For the record, I am running this on RedHat Linux, Google Chrome, .NET Core, with Visual Studio Code. I am trying to use as few special Helper codes as possible. I'm only using `@Html` because it works reliably and easily. Would prefer to use HTML `<input>`.

I have tried repeatedly calling the action and view, but things don't work out. I have used a `for` loop around my text box and submission code. That works, but displays `length` number of textboxes. I don't want that. I want only the one set of text boxes and one submit button.

I am expecting that when a user presses the Add Game submit button that the Game object is added to the series list and returned back to ( or a new set of ) two text boxes to get the next Game object's values and the user presses Add Game.  The user never sees more than two text boxes and the submit button on the page. When a decrementing 'length' value reaches zero, or any other usable counter expires, then we go off and average the values in the list.

I have searched for this for several days and can't find an exactly similar problem where someone solved it.  I know with conditional rendering in Reactjs this would be fairly straightforward, but I am trying to improve my skill with C# and ASP.NET MVC.

UPDATE: SOLVED 07/08/2023

After quite a bit of work and study, I have a possible answer on my own.  My thanks to `MStodd` for patience and help.

When I learned my problem was with the lack of an obvious state mechanism, I began to research how .NET Core provided state.  It is done through a service called `Session`.  I practiced with [Ben Cull's example](https://bencull.com/blog/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core).

This is a minimalist example.  I can scale this up to run a batter's average app without using an array/list.

My Model:

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public int mynumber {get;set;}
    }
```

My Index Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("AtBats", 0);

        return View(mymodel);
    }
```

My Totalizing Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Totalize(ViewModel model)
    {
        

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //You will still get a null warning, but it works
            int atbats = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("AtBats");
            atbats += model.mynumber;
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("AtBats", atbats);
            
            //necessary to view Session value in View (without extra View code)
            ViewBag.AtBats = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("AtBats");
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

My Index View (all that's needed for now):

```
@model app.Models.ViewModel;


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    ViewBag.PageTitle = "Testing";
}

<div>
    <h1>@ViewBag.PageTitle</h1>
    
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Totalize", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mynumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mynumber)
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    }
    @if(ViewBag.AtBats != null){
        <p>At Bats: @ViewBag.AtBats</p>
    }

</div>
```

These `Actions` and `View` produce a total in `ViewBag.AtBats` from whatever number I place in the `TextBoxFor` and then submit. Repeatedly adding a number in the web page and clicking submit cycles through the `Totalize` Action and adds up the total that displays in the web page.

I will post the batter's average app code that descends from this as my answer.

Comment: You're looking to update the next Game object that doesn't have values for hits and atbats in your Batter.series with the values from the text boxes?

Comment: Apologies.  There is missing code.  I would update game.hits and game.atbats with the values from the Texboxes then add 'game' to the series list.  The code is missing because I can't even get the program flow to run correctly where it lets the user enter hits and atbats 'length' times.  Batter.length is the number of games played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MStodd` began heading me in the right direction with a suggestion to look at `HttpContext`.  I recognized this class when I began searching for how .NET Core MVC handles state, specifically state variables. I use these often in `React` when I utilize `useState()`.  I needed something similar to hold variables across page (`View()`) changes.  I decided not to keep the array of games since I also abandoned it in the `React` version.  The key thing is that state variables are held in `HttpContext.Session` class using several methods (e.g. `.SetString()`, `.SetInt32()`).

My Model:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public int hits {get; set;}
        public int atbats {get; set;}
        public bool complete {get; set;} = false;
        public int serieslength {get; set;}
    }
```

My Index Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("hits", 0);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("atbats", 0);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("NumGames", 0);

        return View();
    }
```

My AddGame Action (called repeatedly to add hits and at bats from games):

Note: The (int) cast to `HttpContext.Session.GetInt32()` avoids an error trying to assign a nullable int to a non-nullable int.  VSCode will still give you a warning as does .NET, but because there isn't a null value, it works.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddGame(ViewModel model)
    {
        int hits = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("hits")+model.hits;
        int atbats = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("atbats")+model.atbats;
        int series = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("NumGames");
        series++;
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("NumGames", series);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("hits", hits);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("atbats", atbats);
        ViewBag.Hits = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("hits");
        ViewBag.AtBats = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("atbats");
        ViewBag.Series = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("NumGames");

        if(model.complete){
            return RedirectToAction("Average");
        }else{
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

My Index View (used during Index action and AddGame action):

```
@model batterup.Models.ViewModel;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Batter Up";
    ViewBag.PageTitle = "Batter's Average Calculator";
}

<div>
    <h1>@ViewBag.PageTitle</h1>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("AddGame", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.Label("Enter number of hits: ")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hits)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hits)<br/>
        @Html.Label("Enter number of at bats: ")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.atbats)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.atbats)<br/>
        @Html.Label("Last game (check the box): ")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.complete)<br/>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    }
    @if(ViewBag.Hits != null){
        <p>Hits: @ViewBag.Hits</p>
    }
    @if(ViewBag.AtBats != null){
        <p>At Bats: @ViewBag.AtBats</p>
    }
    @if(ViewBag.Series != null){
        <p>Series length: @ViewBag.Series</p>
    }

</div>
```

There is a final action and View, but I didn't see it as germane to the problem of cycling through the same action while keeping and modifying variable state.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the model you're binding to, you need to make sure all your data is in there. ASP.NET MVC has special list binding syntax, so you could do what I have below.
You could also change your model so that you're just binding to the two values from the boxes and have a hidden ID to look up the already persisted player data; I think that's probably what you were saying but not what your code was.

Make sure to "View Source" and look at what's generated, and set a breakpoint in your controller actions and look at the HttpContext.Current.Request.Form, it might clear up some things.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddGame", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        var printedBoxes = false;

        @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.name )
        @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.length )
        @for(int i = 0; i < this.Model.series.Count; i++)
        {
            var currentGame = this.Model.series[i];
            if (currentGame.atbats == 0 && currentGame.hits == 0 && !printedBoxes)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => this.Model.series[i].atbats)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => this.Model.series[i].hits)
                printedBoxes = true;
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => this.Model.series[i].atbats)
                <br />
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => this.Model.series[i].hits)
            }
        }
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    }
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I will try it later today and reply.

Comment: Yes and no. As written, it displays nothing. If I set printedBoxes to true before entering the view, it displays correctly. Yet, all attempts at recycling through haven't done any better than I had. Apologies for taking a while. I only get to really code on weekends. I was successful at doing it in Reactjs, but without any use of classes. I will share that code, if it helps.

Comment: I have been working with this today.  I have discovered that the real problem is .NET core MVC does not seem to have any concept of a state variable, as does React.  My array of `Game` objects needs to exist outside of any controller action or any View.  The tests I've been running today, even when using `ViewBag` with an array, requires the `ViewBag` variable to be initialized upon entering every controller or else it is null.  Studying session state management right now.  Difficult.  React is much, much simpler.

Comment: @Dave if you need state between requests, then that's up to you, and it's the same for React or any tech using HTTP. You can use session state, or a database or application state, it's up to you. I think you're confusing React state in browser vs state on webserver. ASP.NET doesn't run anything in browser.

Comment: I don't doubt I am confusing the two, except the action of not holding variable values across requests seems the same.  I could not get the app to maintain the value of given variables across requests.  Upon each request to the `AddGame` action, I needed it to totalize the number of hits and at bats and maintain those values until the next request to `AddGame`.  The app is too small to go to all the trouble of saving to a file or a database; so session state did the job. I changed the question because I realized I was asking the wrong question.  Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.